# Javascript can't work simultaneously

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function validate(x) {



        var cur_p = document.getElementById('current').value;
        var new_p = document.getElementById('new').value;
        var con_p = document.getElementById('confirm').value;

        document.getElementById('msg_p').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('msg_cur').innerHTML = '';


        if(x != cur_p)
        {   document.getElementById('msg_cur').innerHTML = ' Your password was incorrect';
            return false;
        }   

        if(new_p != con_p)
        {   document.getElementById('msg_p').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
            return false;
        }

        return (true);

    }
</script>
```

html

```
<form action='change-password.php' method='post' onsubmit="return validate('<?=$current?>')" >
```

I have these on my code.
I can't show the result of these ifs simultaenously.

```
if(x != cur_p)
and 
if(new_p != con_p)
```

if I place the

```
if(x != cur_p){}
```

at the top of

```
if(new_p != con_p){}
```

the response result of if(x != cur_p) will show and the latter will not

and vice versa.

how can i show the result of those two ifs
(assuming that the condition for those were meet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a typo in your code

```
document.getElementById('msg_p').innerHTM = '';  <-- Missing an L
```

Second, of course if you return, it exits the function. So the code will not execute both statements.

Change

```
    if(x != cur_p)
    {   document.getElementById('msg_cur').innerHTML = ' Your password was incorrect';
        return false;
    }   

    if(new_p != con_p)
    {   document.getElementById('msg_p').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
        return false;
    }

    return (true);
```

to

```
    var isValid = true;
    if(x != cur_p)
    {   document.getElementById('msg_cur').innerHTML = ' Your password was incorrect';
        isValid = false;
    }   

    if(new_p != con_p)
    {   document.getElementById('msg_p').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
```

Comment: the missing 'L' in 'HTM' is not the reason i guess.
but your second solution is GREAT.
thank you so much @epascarello you saves my day

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are returning `false` after the first, so the second is never reached. Instead, set a boolean variable in each and return the boolean variable (which will be `true` if neither fails, or `false` if either fails).

```
    // Boolean variable starts true, will get set to false if either condition is met:
    var okFlag = true;
    if(x != cur_p)
    {   document.getElementById('msg_cur').innerHTML = ' Your password was incorrect';
        // Set to false
        okFlag = false;
    }   

    if(new_p != con_p)
    {   document.getElementById('msg_p').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
        // Set to false
        okFlag = false;
    }
    // Return the flag, which is either true or false.
    return okFlag;
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the question!